# Cannot update state in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, filter, use-state

```
 console.log(holder);
 console.log(index);

 console.log(holder);
 setWholeData(wholeData.filter((el, i) => i !== index));
 console.log(holder);
```

For the above code, I want to remove one element with index = 'index' in wholeData which is a state setup using useState and initialize with []. In my test case, before this part of code, wholedata should have two elements and this part of code should remove one of its elements. I assign the updated/New array to holder and want to assign it to wholedata using 'setWholeData()".

But the problem is that if I do 
`setWholeData(holder)`. Then the holder will contain two elements, which means that the filter function did not work somehow. If I do
`setWholeData(wholeData.filter((el, i) => i !== index));`
The value of holder is what I expected, but 'wholedata' is not updated correctly still. The element is not removed. Seems like the filter in the 
`setWholeData(...)` is not working.

If anyone could give a little hand, it would be so appreciated. Sorry for the confusing description, if any clarification is needed, please feel free to message.

Comment: fyi `setWholeData` is async so you can't log straight after it and expect the result, you might as well have a single console log for `holder` as the component will re-render after the set

Answer (score 0):

Filter returns an array where the result of the callback is 'true'. 
If you want to remove an element by its index you can use a combination of findIndex and splice to find the index of the element you want to remove and splice to execute the removal of that element.